# Cascading Drop Downs in SharePoint  with One Web Part Only

Tags: sharepoint, drop-down-menu

I need your suggestions for my problem area. I am working with SharePoint 2010. My requirement is to create a single web part that has only one DropDown List. Say DropDown List for continents. Now I want to use the same web part more than once on my page to have a cascading effect e.g Continents|Countries|States|Cities|so on.

So my single web part can accept and provide connections.

Though I have been able to create a both provider and consumer web part but I am strucked with post backs. Ever time a DropDown's value is changed all the other DropDowns get bound again and lost the values.

Please suggest me some options.

Thanks a lot.

Kind Regards
Vivek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the answer for a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463555/why-drop-down-gets-reset-after-post-back). Check if your dropdowns are rebound on postback. If so make them bound only once.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the Querystrings to store the dropdown state. This would also help you in creating Deep Url's. We did the same thing on the sharepoint features page here : http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/Pages/Features.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if ViewState of dropdowns is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cascade dropdown based on Client Object Model.

Take a look at this utility i just released : http://sylvainlancien.blogspot.fr/2013/11/slnspcascadingdropdown-jquery-cascade.html